# Spring AOP in a non Spring project

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have a project in wich I would like to use some benefits of AOP, this wasn't made from me so I can't change too much about configuration, at this step is where I need some advice due I want to use Spring AOP but, when or how initialice correctly the Spring context?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you intended to do since there are plenty ways to setup a spring context. The simplest way is ClasspathXmlApplicationContext:

```
ClasspathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClasspathXmlApplicationContext("root-context.xml");
```

Here root-context.xml is a xml bean configuration file searched on classpath root. Typically you'd put this on src/main/resources.

Comment: Good, I will try with this too

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP relies on the Spring framework and only works with Spring Beans. So you cannot use it without the Spring framework. What you want to use is AspectJ. It only needs one runtime library and works with POJOs, in application servers, with EJBs or even in combination wirth Spring. It does not need any dynamic proxies because it instruments your code directly during compilation or dynamically during class-loading. It is faster, leaner and much more powerful than Spring AOP.

Comment: You are right, but I like the combination of Spring and AspectJ because together seem to make more easy the process so I will try the idea given by @gerrytan, in other case I will use just AspectJ, thank you

Comment: Then please change the subject of your question, because if you use Spring AOP you also use Spring and are far from the idea of a non-Spring project. I repeat: Each single class or interface you want to advise must be a Spring component if you want this to work with Spring AOP. Furthermore, a combination of Spring AOP and AspectJ is necessarily more complex (not easier) than either single one of them. I just think it does not make sense because you wrote you do not want to use Spring. But then you have to!